# Hijack vertex delete in leaflet editable?

Tags: leaflet

Is there an easy way to hijack the editable:vertex:rawclick event in Leaflet editable so that delete vertex isn't triggered? I'm trying to add an extra step with a pop up when deleting a vertex.

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the event in a custom handler:

```
        map.on('editable:vertex:rawclick', function(e) {
            e.cancel();
        });
```

This will cause the default handler to return before deleting the vertex.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
const lines = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-marker-icon');
for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    lines[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
    });
}
```